# compare values of different table columns and return when they match

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 tables with data like this:
Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

I would like to compare the values of both tables and return them when they match. In the example the returned rows would be order 1(personX is same as personX) and order 7(person Z is same as personZ).

How to do this?

I hope you guys can help me out!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do an [intersection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/intersect-function-dax) of the two tables,

```
INTERSECT(CreatedTable, VerifiedTable)
```

you'll get this table:

```
Order  Created By
1      PersonX
7      PersonZ
```